# deleting object from realm database.

Tags: swift, realm

I am writing Todo app. My app is simple. I have two pages. One page for showing tasks in table view. And one page for adding new tasks. In this page I post to server and then in main page I get data from server and then save it in realm database.

When I Want to delete them in my main page , my app crashes by this error.

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TodoApp.TodosTableViewController delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fca7b40b4c0
```

Anyone knows why? 
It is my deleting function :

```
public func delete<T:Object>(_ model: T) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    try! realm.write {
        
        realm.delete(model)
        
        }
}
```

And this is the place that I use this function to delete from database :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            rowHere = indexPath.row
            // it crashes the app when I want to delete from database
            
//            delete(self.todos[self.rowHere!])
            
            self.todos.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with:           UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            
            
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm puzzled. Why don't you already have a realm instance before calling this?  If you created it using an instance of realm you should delete from that same instance.

Comment: Where does your function `delete()` live? Is it a method on your `TodosTableViewController` class?

Comment: @Mozahler , I have global functions for deleting and reading and saving on database. that's why each time I make a new objects. I checked your idea. It does not work.

Comment: @AustinZ My deleting object is not in TodosTableViewController. It is a global function that does not belong to any classes.

Comment: Well, that's why your code is failing. You are trying to call a method on your table view controller that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that that problem comes from "delete" word. It seems that this word preserved for Xcode. When I call it , it goes to another delete method in another place not mine. I changed the name to for example deleteSomethings and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented something similar in my app, hope it helps you.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //deleteRecords()
    delete(index: indexPath.row)
    retrieveFoods()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func retrieveFoods() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    myFoodsArray = realm.objects(MyFoods.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
}

func delete(index: Int) {
    let myFood = myFoodsArray[index]
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(myFood)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: func delete(index: Int) is this func delete only selected item but not from Realm DB?

Comment: It should delete from the database on the realm.delete(myFood)

Answer (score 1):

First get `Object` model in `viewDidLoad()`

```
var DatabaseModel: Results<ObjectClassRealm>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let realm = RealmService.shared.realm
    DatabaseModel = realm.objects(ObjectClassRealm.self)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
    let objectData = DatabaseModel[indexPath.row]
    RealmService.shared.delete(objectData)
}
```

Or you can delete on button click

```
@IBAction func DeleteData(_ sender: Any) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let deleteData = realm.object(ofType: ObjectClassRealm.self, 
                                  forPrimaryKey: PRIMARYKEY)
    if deleteData == nil {
        print("No data in DB")
    } else {
        RealmService.shared.delete(deleteData!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the error message is deceiving.
You haven't shown where you define the class property rowHere (as an integer), but the variable isn't needed here.

```
delete(self.todos[self.rowHere!])
```

if todos is an array of your realm Object subclass, then this should work:

```
   let objectToDelete = self.todos[indexPath.row]
   delete(objectToDelete])
```

as long as your delete is something like this: (my Realm instance is called realmStore)

```
func delete(objectToDelete: Object) // use your subclass name
    do {
       try realmStore.write {
          realmStore.delete(record)
       }
    } catch {
       print("Could not delete object.\n\(String(describing: error.localizedDescription))"
}
```